# Problem with understanding an equation used to define a monoid on the natural numbers

Tags: haskell, monoids

Consider following code:

```
import Data.Semigroup
newtype Sum a = Sum { getSum :: a } deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

instance Num a => Semigroup (Sum a) where
Sum a <> Sum b = Sum (a + b)

instance Num a => Monoid (Sum a) where
mempty = Sum 0
mappend = (<>)
```

I don't really understand what the line `newtype Sum a = Sum { getSum :: a }` means. A new type is being defined, polymorphic on `a`. `getSum :: Sum a -> a` returns something of type `a` which can therefore combine with Sum. But why do we need `getSum` here, and what is `{` and `}` doing?

What is the point of using record syntax in this case?

Comment: The same point as always for using Record syntax - that you get the "deconstructor" function `getSum` already named as part of the type definition. It's not essential though, and would work just the same if the type was defined as `newtype Sum a = Sum a` (except that you wouldn't have a natural function `Sum a -> a` without defining it yourself).

Comment: how much experience of Haskell do you have? Not trying to be rude, I just ask because definitions like `data Foo a = Foo a` do look weird at first, but are very common - the apparent repetition isn't actually such, because the `Foo` on the left is a type while the one on the right is a data constructor (which is not a type but a function value). (And using `newtype` instead of `Data` makes no difference to this.)

Comment: So ``Sum`` on the r.h.s of the equality takes something of type ``a`` and returns something of type ``Sum a``

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the `{}` indicates record syntax. Consider this to represent a person with a name and an age:

```hs
newtype Person = Person String Int
getName :: Person -> String
getName (Person x _) = x
getAge :: Person -> Int
getAge (Person _ x) = x
```

This works fine, but now consider if you want to add a home address and a social security number:

```hs
newtype Person = Person String Int String Int
getName :: Person -> String
getName (Person x _ _ _) = x
getAge :: Person -> Int
getAge (Person _ x _ _) = x
getAddress :: Person -> String
getAddress (Person _ _ x _) = x
getSsn :: Person -> Int
getSsn (Person _ _ _ x) = x
```

This is already getting messy. And what if you want to set a value? That's where record syntax comes in:

```hs
 -- this is generally spaced out onto multiple lines
newtype Person = Person { getName :: String, getAge :: Int, getAddress :: String, getSsn :: Int }
```

You can still construct  a person via a construct like `Person name age addr ssn`, but you can also construct a person via a construct like `Person {getAddress = "foo", getSsn = 123, getAge = 12, getName = "bar"}`. When using record syntax, the functions `getName :: Person -> String`, `getAge :: Person -> Int`, `getAddress :: Person -> String`, and `getSsn :: Person -> Int` are automatically defined. It's basically automatic unwrapping. This is really convenient, so many times haskellers define their data with record syntax to add an automatic unwrapper or deconstructor:

```hs
newtype Sum a = Sum { getSum :: a }

x :: Sum Int
x = Sum 1

y :: Int
y = getSum x

-- the alternative without record syntax:
newtype Sum' a = Sum' a

getSum' :: Sum' a -> a
getSum' (Sum' x) = x

x' :: Sum' Int
x' = Sum' 1

y' :: Int
y' = getSum' x
```

Both are equivalent, but the first is shorter, which is why it's used more often.

Comment: I find it rather inelegant that the same expression-- ``Sum``--is used as both a type constructor and as a data constructor. Also, what's confusing me is that ``Sum' a`` seems to have a different meaning on the two sides of the equation.

Comment: Doesn't ``Sum' a`` on the r.h.s mean that ``Sum'`` applied to something of type ``a`` (where ``a`` stands for a given type) forms an expression of type ``Sum a``, whereas, on the l.h.s, ``Sum' a`` means that the sum type constructor applied to the TYPE ``a`` results in a type ``Sum' a``. So the same expressions ``Sum`` and ``a`` are being used in a wildly different way, and I find this really confusing.

Comment: In general, constructors and types occupy a different name space, so yes, you can have `Sum 3 :: Sum Int`. If you find that confusing you can write `data Sum a = SomeSum a` (and I think the same with newtype, but I haven’t used a different type and constructor name so I’m not sure); you don’t have to write the same thing. I can see how `data` declarations can be confusing though, and I sympathize.

Comment: @cole Indeed, that works just as well with newtypes.

Comment: @Cole It's not only that which I find confusing. ``a`` is used ambiguously: on the l.h.s, ``a`` denotes a type, whereas on the l.h.s, ``a`` denotes something which has type ``a``. This is surely scandalous! eheh :)

Comment: @user65526 I agree, that is also confusing now that I think about it. You might find [GADT Syntax](https://typeclasses.com/ghc/gadt-syntax) more intuitive, although I don’t know what style consensuses are on using it when you don’t have to.